# How to assign an Owner using the Hubspot API?

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm

I'm using the Hubspot API to create new contacts and would like to automatically set the owner when the contact is created. I know this is possible without using the API via Workflows, however I'd like to use the API for that.

Here's my code right now (which works, just missing the contact owner):

```
$data = [
    'properties' => [
                        ['property' => 'firstname', 'value' => $contact->first_name],
                        ['property' => 'lastname', 'value' => $contact->last_name],
                    ]
];

$body = json_encode($data);
$response = $client->request('POST', '/contacts/v1/contact/email/'.$user->email.'/profile',
                ['query' => ['hapikey' => $hubspot_key, 'body' => $body]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I eventually found a way to achieve this:

1. Go to your Hubspot instance, then **Settings** and **Properties**
2. Search for "**Contact Owner**" and click on **Edit**
3. In "**Field type**", identify the Owner's ID **value**

Then in your API call, simply pass this property:

```
$data['properties'][] = ['property' => 'hubspot_owner_id', 'value' => 123456];
```

You can find out more about the `hubspot_owner_id` property (which is internal to Hubspot, this is not a custom property) in [Hubspot's documentation](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/owners).

It will automatically assign the newly created (or updated) Hubspot contact to the related Owner (Hubspot User).

Comment: For anyone looking for a quick alternative to list the owners, you could use `curl` . For this method you require an HubSpot API Key, make sure you replace `HUB_API_KEY` with your API key in the following code: `curl 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/owners/?hapikey=HUB_API_KEY&limit=500'`. Or filtering by email: `curl 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/owners/?hapikey=HUB_API_KEY&email=youremail@company.com'`

Comment: not sure why, but now when sending hubspot_owner_id, the api returns an error. Did anything change?

Answer (score 0):

An update to Bruno Leveque's answer:

```
$data['properties'][] = 'hubspot_owner_id' => 123456,
```

The old

```
$data['properties'][] = ['property' => 'hubspot_owner_id', 'value' => 123456];
```

Is giving an error